# How to open a terminal inside a sub-directory from django

Tags: command-line, bash, python, django

I am learning django. I am stuck with this problem.

I want to open a new terminal and execute a command in it. Here is the code that I used to do it.

`run(["gnome-terminal", "--", "sh", "-c", f"espeak -ven+m1 -f {file_name.name} -w {fbh}.wav "])`

I have written the above code in my views.py file. Here, `{file_name.name}` is the name of the text file I take as input from the user `{fbh}` is the name of the generated audio file.

Everything works perfectly but the problem is that the terminal opens in `auto_generation` directory and executes the code namely, `espeak -ven+m1 -f {file_name.name} -w {fbh}.wav` there but I want that it should open in `media` directory and execute the code there. `media` is a sub-directory of the  `auto_generation` directory.

Can someone please suggest me what changes I should do to the above command so that the new terminal opens in `media` directory instead of `auto_generation` directory?

As I already said I am new to django and some help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Django is a web framework, it is not supposed to call a GUI tool like `gnome-terminal`.

  Use `python-espeak` or call `espeak` directly without any shell-emulator.
- You may include path with filename or use Python function to change directory or use as `cd  ...; speak` with a shell command.